# Why Jquery Ajax call returns html instead of Json

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have written Jquery Ajax function that calls MVC server side method, but my problem is that it returns html instead of Json string, and it throws an error when it tries to Parse the the returned html.

The same code works fine(returns Json string) on other App Services.
What could be the issue with this App Service?
Do I need to change a setting on the App Service or something?

Here is my source code:

**MVC**

```
[HttpPost]
[NoDirectAccess]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string email, string password)
{
  //run business logic
  //return results
  return Json(new { isValid = false, message = "", exception = "", html = "" });
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Login","MyController")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: postData,
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (res) {
                         console.log(JSON.parse(res)); //it throws an error here
                    }
});
```

**Error**

```
VM466:6  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "
<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

Comment: Perhaps the `NoDirectAccess` is blocking call to that Action and the HTML being returned is the error web page. Did you try debugging and checking if the action is being hit?

Comment: seems like `Login` is the function. so change it to `url: '@Url.Action("MyController","Login")',`

Comment: @JonesJoseph The returned html shows the landing page with the log out button, which means the transaction was successful.                                                                           The server side function gets triggered, the only problem is that the returned response is the html instead of json string.

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant the controller/action overload for `@Url.Action` is `@Url.Action(Action, Controller)` - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-urlhelper-action(system-string-system-string)

Comment: `dataType: "html",` - you're telling the server that it should return HTML.   Depending on how your .net app is setup, `return Json` could be converted to HTML as that's what you've *requested*.   If it's just an Action, not a webapi endpoint then probably not - but to save confusion you should probably change this to `dataType: "text",` if you're going to parse the result yourself, or `dataType: "json",` to have jquery parse the result (in both cases assuming you get json and not html).

Comment: `//run business logic` - looks like your "business logic" is **returning or redirecting** to a different page before it gets to your `return Json` (given your comment above).  Try removing all the business logic - move the `return Json` line to be the *first* line in the action to see if you get the expected json result back without it doing anything else.

Comment: Thank you for advice team. I fixed the issue by changing datatype to 'text' and also returning http status code like this :  return Ok(Json(new { isValid = false, message = "", exception = "", html = "" }));

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing the datatype to **'text'** and also returning http status code on server side :

return **Ok(**Json(new { isValid = false, message = "", exception = "", html = "" })**)**;